# Swift - View inside UIScrollView not touched while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, swift3

I have a custom view inside a `UIScrollView`
Tapping/touching works perfectly if `UIScrollView` is not scrolling.

However, when it is scrolling, I need to tap the scrollview first to stop the scrolling, then tap again the scrollview to select my custom view.

Upon searching, I ended up with **`scrollViewDidEndDragging`**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
  if(!decelerate){             
         print(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.location(in: scrollView))
         //tap scrollview again but now programmatically

  }
}
```

I wanted to tap the scrollview again with the location(`CGPoint`) where the last tap location is, but couldn't find any way to do it.

But, if you have any idea on touching my custom view inside `UIScrollView` while scrolling, that would be really great.

Thank you!

Comment: There are ways in which you can programatically create touch events, but these use private apis and there is a very high probability that your app would get rejected by apple. As far as I know, it is standard behaviour of ios to stop scrolling before forwarding the touch event to any of the controls within the view.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This is not a behaviour that user would expect.